# CodeIgniter passing parameters to a function in CORE MY_Controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I hope that this is possible

Can I pass parameters to functions in CORE/MY_Controller?

I am developing a application that has three controllers and most of the functions are the same so I want to code functions ones and use them again in their respectable controllers when need.

function like search_User_Name() will be in both of the controllers, it will be cool if i can get to code it once and reuse it. the problems that i am facing at the moment are

1. The MY_Controller.php is not in the same folders as other controllers
2. The search_User_Name() function has to receive parameters like search_User_Name($var1, $var2)

I have a controller in the core folder as MY_Controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
             parent::__construct();
    }

    public function Testing($var){
     $function_var= $var;
     return $function_var;
   }
}
```

and i have a controller in the controller folder as Sub_Controlller

```
class Sub_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function Show(){
        echo($this->Testing());
    }
}
```

on the view i have

```
echo anchor('Sub_Controller/Show/Parameter','Pass a parameter');
```

according to my understanding i was spouse to get the word "parameter" on the screen. 
can any help?

Comment: I suggest you to read the OOP chapters on the PHP doc, but for your case you can read this 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php then read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: thanx for the links, but if any problems then i post more questions. "i'm starting to talk machine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine, but you still need to pass in the arguments:

```
class Sub_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function Show($arg = null) {
        echo($this->Testing($arg));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can read the URI segment from the base function, but then you have less control:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function Testing() {
        $function_var = $this->uri->segment(2);
        return $function_var;
   }
}
class Sub_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function Show() {
        echo($this->Testing()); // prints the argument in the URL
    }
}
```

Better to do it the first way.